# Which was better for your web site: Facebook Like or Share button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We only want to implement one and are curious which one worked better for people.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Like Button as a share button. No more Share Button :) [article](http://www.socialnomics.net/2011/02/28/facebook-kills-share-button-enhances-like-button/)